# could not connect to server: can't connect postgres on the server to postico on my local

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, psql

when I connect postgres on the server to postico on my local I get this error

```
could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "http://159.65.65.203/" (92.242.140.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I could not find anywhere postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files, so i created the files, as you see in the below image

[image]

I found this explanation but still does not solve my issue

```
Ubuntu does not use the standard pg_ctl for postgreSQL. Instead, it 
uses pg_ctlcluster.
That in turn controls the different PostgreSQL clusters. When you do 
an install of a new cluster, pg_ctlcluster is smart enough to put
postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf into separate dirs.
So to be specific, /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf is just a tmp 
file that you can ingnore, /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf is 
the original version for the 9.4 cluster and
/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.auto.conf is the actual, live
version of the 9.4 cluster that you need to change to affect the 9.4
cluster. Likewise for the pg_hba.conf.
reference https://www.postgresql.org/message- 
id/CANu8FiygR5CdeqRTiE0YM+BQk6aK+qZyw2frH_FWV27J1exong@mail.gmail.com
```

here how i configured postgresql.conf

```
port=5432
listen_addresses='*'
```

here how i configured pg_hba.conf

```
 host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
 host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

when i run

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program 
name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
29761/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Clearly 5432 is not open for all connections.
when i make an api call using postman seems to work.
I use mac currently firewall not on, i have my server on digitalocean use Ubuntu 16.04.6 (LTS) x64.

This is the path of postgres files

```
postgres@borroupapi:~/9.5/main$
```

when i run  find / -name postgresql.conf i get this

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```

but i cant find the path as logged in postgres user

Comment: Starting with the error message, it's quite puzzling that you seem to provide `http://159.65.65.203/` as the host to connect to (where does that come from?)  and that it seems to resolve to `92.242.140.2`.

Comment: Anyway it seems like a firewall at digitalocean is blocking 5432 (which makes sense) and you'd better use an [SSH tunnel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssh-tunnels.html) to use postgresql remotely rather than opening that port for the internet to try to hack into your instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue in postgres 9.5 postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files are located in

```
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

not in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

you have to login as server root user and run each one of the command and that will give where are the files

```
find / -name postgresql.conf

find / -name pg_hba.conf
```

in my instance when i ran the command i got this

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf
```